# Error Xamp doesn't work

Tags: xampp

After loading a database on xamp, the program doesn't work

This is the log file

```
2016-09-28 14:46:03 115c InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2016-09-28 14:46:03 4444 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-09-28 14:46:03 4444 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-09-28 14:46:03 4444 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-09-28 14:46:03 4444 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-09-28 14:46:03 4444 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-09-28 14:46:03 4444 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-09-28 14:46:03 4444 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 160.0M
2016-09-28 14:46:03 4444 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-09-28 14:46:03 4444 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-09-28 14:46:03 4444 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1835037 and 1835037 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 2351448096 in the ib_logfiles!
2016-09-28 14:46:03 4444 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2016-09-28 14:46:03 4444 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2016-09-28 14:46:03 4444 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2016-09-28 14:46:03 4444 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace american/ps_desktop_menu_tabs_shop uses space ID: 13969 at filepath: .\american\ps_desktop_menu_tabs_shop.ibd. Cannot open tablespace american2/ps_desktop_menu_tabs_shop which uses space ID: 13969 at filepath: .\american2\ps_desktop_menu_tabs_shop.ibd
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\american2\ps_desktop_menu_tabs_shop.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
```

How i can solve?
I can't reinstall the program because i've a lot of database for work

Comment: This was probably an unclean shutdown. I suggest you proceed how mentioned in option 2.

Comment: what's the option 2?

Comment: You never even bothered to _read_ the error message you get? Ok...

Comment: Sorry arkascha, sure I read it, I did not realize you made reference to that. i tried to replace (or delete) these files, but the problem persists, the files that tells me with ano error are all files that have size of 96kb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, go to services and search for MySQL services after getting it to delete the services and restart the camp will work fine

Answer (score 0):

go check your Xamp folder file in cfolder  that probelem fixed.to erase that problem to comeagain xamp is worked.